# jquery have .on() execute immediately

Tags: jquery

Seems pretty trivial and I'm somehow not able to find a good resource.

I have ajax-loaded content, therefore the JS itself is not loaded into the dom.  Later on, I want to add a class to what I just loaded previously (in this example, with class name "loaded").  Everything I see on .on() has "click" as the event type or "submit", e.g.

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".loaded", function() {
   $(this).addClass("success");
});
```

However, I want the addClass to be fired right when I call this code and not when the user clicks.  I must be missing something here as I'm sure this is often needed.

Comment: You want to add the class at first pageload when the document is ready, or do you want to add the class when something is loaded with ajax ?

Comment: when something is loaded with ajax.  I'm using the jquery file uploaded, and on done I want to add a class to an element that was previously loaded with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you're talking about jQuery FileUpload plugin:

```
$(function () {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        // ...

        // When the upload is complete, addClass.
        done: function () {
            $('.loaded').addClass('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, you use the callback function when the file has successfully loaded using:

```
done: function () {
    $('.loaded').addClass('success');
}
```

Or, if you're just wanting to add the class on DOMready:

```
$('.loaded').addClass('success');
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to add class `success` to all element with class `loaded` right after executing js code. Therefore, solution you're looking for is quite simple:

```
$(".loaded").addClass("success");
```

Comment: You know what, I just realized that it really was that simple.  I'm sorry.  I had a syntax earlier on and I wasn't calling the correct class.  brb, getting coffee and a nap.